# AngularJS : after isolating scope and binding to a parentFunction, how to pass parameters to this parentFunction?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying very hard to understand scopes in AngularJS and am running into problems.
I've created a simple "comments" application that

1. has an input box for publishing a comment (text + 'Reply' button) [this is working fine]
2. clicking 'Reply' button unhides another input box for publishing a reply (with a 'PublishReply' button)
3. clicking 'PublishReply' button, publishes the reply below the original comment and also indents it.

I generate comments within 'commentsDirective' using ng-repeat and embed a 'replyDirective' within each ng-repeat. I'm able to bind the parent scope's functions from the child directive's isolated scope, but I'm just not able to pass the arguments to this function.

Again, I think, a scope related problem is preventing me to hide/unhide the 'replyDirective' from the on-click of 'Reply' button.

Grateful for your help.

Here is the code in plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/5AmlbOh6iEPby9K2LJDE?p=preview

```
<body ng-app="comments">
    <div ng-controller="mainController">
        <div class="publishComment"><input type="text" ng-model="contentForPublishing"/><button ng-click="publishComment(null, 0, contentForPublishing)">Publish Comment</button></div>
        <comments-directive></comments-directive>
    </div>
</body>


<script>
    angular.module('comments', [])
            .controller('mainController', function($scope) {
                $scope.comments = [
                    { id: 1, parentId: 0, content:'first comment'},
                    { id: 2, parentId: 0, content:'second comment'}
                ];
                $scope.publishComment = function (commentId, commentParentId, contentForPublishing){
                    if (commentId === null) {commentId = $scope.comments.length + 1;} // this (commentId === null) is sent only from the publishComments and not from publishReply
                    $scope.comments.push( { id: commentId, parentId:commentParentId, content:contentForPublishing } );
                    $scope.contentForPublishing = "";
                }
                $scope.replyWidgetVisible = false;
                $scope.showReplyWidget = function() {
                    $scope.replyWidgetVisible = true;
                }
            })
            .directive('commentsDirective', function() {
                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
//                    template:   '<div id="{{comment.id}}" class="commentWrapper" ng-class="{{ {true: '', false: 'indentLeft'}[{{comment.parentId}} === 0] }}" ng-repeat="comment in comments">' +
                    template:   '<div id="{{comment.id}}" class="commentWrapper" ng-repeat="comment in comments">' +
                                    'id: {{comment.id}} parentId: {{comment.parentId}}<br>>> {{comment.content}}<br>' +
                                    '<button class="reply" ng-click="showReplyWidget()">Reply</button>' +
//                                    '<reply-directive publish-reply="publishComment()" ng-show="{{replyWidgetVisible}}" reply-widget-visible="replyWidgetVisible"></reply-directive>' +
                                    '<reply-directive publish-reply="publishComment()" comments-array="comments"></reply-directive>' +
                                '</div>'
                };
            })
            .directive('replyDirective', function() {
                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
                    scope: {
                        publishReply: '&',
                        commentsArray: '=',
                        replyWidgetVisible: '='
                    },
                    template: '<div class="publishComment"><input type="text" ng-model="contentForPublishing"/><button ng-click="publishReply(5, 1, contentForPublishing)">Publish Reply</button></div>'
                };
            });
</script>
```

Comment: You are trying to assign `contentForPublishing` to the parent scope, but you aren't creating a two way binding for it. You are also creating 2 elements with the same directive, but they each have a different scope. They should be put together (since you can have one reply for each comment)

Comment: I'm not trying to assign contentForPublishing to the parent scope because I'm fine with contentForPublishing existing separately on both the parent and the isolated scope. In the isolated scope, I'm merely intending to use it as an attribute for the publishReply(). As of now, this publishReply() is not even accepting hard coded values. Thanks for going through it though.

Comment: that's easy enough to fix, will put the answer in a bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you need to "fetch" the publishComment function, since with `publish-reply="publishComment()"` you are telling Angular to call `publishComment` without any arguments, regardless of the arguments you are passing on your isolated scope. So, to actually reach the `publishComment` function (and not only the predefined executing function), so you can pass in arguments, you need to:

```js
.directive('commentsDirective', function() {
    return {
       restrict: 'E',
       template:   '<div id="{{comment.id}}" class="commentWrapper"     ng-repeat="comment in comments">' +
         'id: {{comment.id}} parentId: {{comment.parentId}}<br>>> {{comment.content}}<br>' +
         '<button class="reply" ng-click="showReplyWidget()">Reply</button>' +
         '<reply-directive publish-reply="publishReply()" comments-array="comments"></reply-directive>' +
       '</div>',
       link: function(scope){
         scope.publishReply = function(){
           return scope.publishComment;
         }
       }
    };
})
```

```js
.directive('replyDirective', function() {
    return {
       restrict: 'E',
       scope: {
           publishReply: '&',
           commentsArray: '=',
           replyWidgetVisible: '='
       },
       template: '<div class="publishComment"><input type="text"      ng-model="contentForPublishing"/><button ng-click="publishReply(5, 1,     contentForPublishing)">Publish Reply</button></div>',
       link: function(scope) {
         scope.publishReply = scope.publishReply();
       }
    };
});
```

Think it like if you were doing: `(function(){ return scope.publishComment(); })(5, 1, contentForPublishing);`

Doing a "get reference to function" parent scope binding is mainly useful when the passed function is mutable. for example, `my-cool-function="doThis()"` and on another part of your app `my-cool-function="doThat()"`. they exist so you can reuse the same directive in many situations, which isn't the case here.

A much simpler way would to `$emit` a publish event from your isolated scope and catch it in your comments directive. Or create a scope with `true` so you can access, in your newly created child scope, the function directly from the parent.

See updated plnkr in here http://plnkr.co/edit/nOWwFJ35XRXaIoxNPlW4?p=preview

Here is the plnkr showing how to keep just one reply box opened (you can keep as many open if you wish) http://plnkr.co/edit/za16eHPzltGLjK5ra1Vb?p=preview (see the revision before it for a widget state for each comment)

Comment: Clearly this works. Thanks. But I'm not getting how 'commentsDirective' has access to scope.publishReply (is it because I bound them in the isolate scope definition with '=' ?). Let me pls. re-read it tomorrow (it's 3:29am here). Also, can you please look into the $scope.replyWidgetVisible ? Why doesn't it work if line 35 is uncommented and line 36 is commented ? Thanks again.

Comment: I'm going to edit the plnkr. It's because the "replyWidgetVisible" is a 'global' state that is set on the main controller scope. the state of each "widget visible" must be bound to the comment item from your ng-repeat, so that it doesnt a) show the reply widget on all your comments b) you can keep track and keep just one reply widget open at a time